# How to decide the number of threads or Virtual users for my scenario in JMeter

Tags: performance, wcf, testing, jmeter

My application under test is a WCF web service whose performance I need to test. there are more than 50000 hardware devices that communicate with the web service on daily basis.

The communication of all the 50000 devices is completed within 5 hours.

Can someone help in derive a scenario for load testing and how many Virtual users should I create because ultimately each device is actually querying the web service. So I can keep 1 virtual user and run it 50000 times or should I create 50000 virtual users or something between both...?

Answer (score 1):

Your load test needs to represent real-life application usage as close as it is possible otherwise it doesn't make sense. So if your application acts as a backend for devices you need to simulate real usage of the backend with this devices.

50 000 devices per 5 hours give 10 000 devices per hour which is about 166 devices per minute.

Good idea would be setting number of threads (virtual users) for the [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to be more or less equal to the number of devices which simultaneously connect to the backend. Once done you should be able to limit JMeter's request rate to 166 requests per minute using [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer).

You might need to adjust above target throughput value depending on the number of requests which is being made by each individual device.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its a good practice to create 50000 users.
When you test for large amount of users, there is possibility that it crashes. It depends on

- machine power
- OS
- jvm(32/64 bits)
- test plan

One of the solution is you can consider using less users and using loops to do your task.

more answers could be found here

https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/17732/maximum-number-of-threads-in-jmeter